# What is Electric-flux?

Tags: electricity

I've searched the question in the forum, and found the following conclusion : -

"In electromagnetism, electric flux is the **rate of flow of the electric field** through a **given area.** Electric flux is proportional to the **number of electric field lines** going through a virtual surface.

But, It doesn't make intuitive sense to me, that electric flux is just something that we can count like no. of lines, I don't think electric field is passing in lines literally, so what exactly is Electric flux? and Rate of flow suggest that it's moving like water flow in river. These ideas are difficult for me to grasp, please clarify.

Comment: "Lines of force" is a bad metaphor for electric or magnetic flux, but it is retained for historical reasons.  If it is the discrete aspect of this concept that is bothering you, then you are correct to be bothered.  The fields are continuous (at least in the classical or non-quantum realm).  You have to understand that this concept originated before the concept of a field was developed so it played an important role  historically.

Comment: Great! But then what flux exactly is? It is denoted by phy equal E.da =E.dacos(x) what I am doing here is just multiplying area and electric field intensity. So is it just the opposite of "Pressure" in a sense? I mean pressure is force acting per unit area , and here we are multiplying intensity to total area?

Comment: You could think of it as a potential pressure.  Its not a real pressure unless there is something to push against.  If you did place a charged surface in that position it would be either pushed (for like charges) or pulled (for unlike charges).  Electric flux is really the density of energy stored in the electric field that surrounds a charge.  I think Gauss' theorem is the best way to understand this concept:  The total electric flux emerging from any closed surface is equal to the net positive charge enclosed within the surface.  Note the use of "emerging from" rather than "flowing through."

Comment: Well explained. Potential pressure, totally make sense it can be compared to a "Guard(electric charged particle" that will be idle unless someone tries to get in the field, and as soon as he notice some positive charge entering his territory, he will push according to his strength(electric intensity E). But what the word "density" can be compared to here?. From density I understand any characteristic like weight, charge per unit volume/area/length of something. So what could be density of energy??

Comment: My point is, if we divide electric field intensity by the area it makes some sense as if something working on larger area the intensity may reduce. But multiplying area to the intensity, is simply like multiplying to an arbitrary factor that is not related to it.